# How valuable are publications in lower-ranked conferences for MS admission applications?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, conference, computer-science

I have finished my undergraduate in Computer Science and am currently looking for admissions to top US universities for doing my MS.

I have a publication in the [IEEE International Conference on Computational Intelligence and Computing Research](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/conferencedetails/index.html?Conf_ID=40999), to be published in IEEE XPLORE. The conference has a h5-index of 13 and a h5 median of 17 in Google Scholar.

I am unsure about the value of this publication and what impact it would have on my MS applications for top US universities. Would it impact negatively or positively and if it does impact positively, how far would it help in the admissions?

I am querying about the value of the specific conference mentioned above and its potential impact on my MS application.

Comment: You asked the question yesterday. Patience. If you want to give the question extra visibility, than ask and answer questions to get reputation, and set a bounty on the question. Don't make spurious edits.

Answer (score 2):

When applying for grad school, the biggest thing is to demonstrate aptitude in research. You do not need to have a paper in a top-ranked conference to get into a good grad school. The fact that you have a conference paper is significant enough as it is.

Will a top-ranked conference paper *improve* your chances over a paper in a lower-ranked conference? Yes, of course. But having a conference paper in a reputable conference should never hurt your standing.

Comment: Thanks a lot aeismail. I also wanted to know how good the specific conference mentioned above actually is and how suitable it would be for my admissions.

Comment: Not my area, so I can't really judge.